# subscribe function in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-observables, subscribe

I want to see the result returned from the service in the same subscribe method or in the ngOninit method(commented one) but neither of the place it showing the result even it is fetching the result from the service..

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.cityAreaService.getCities().subscribe(data => {
        this.cities = data;
        //console.log(this.cities);
    });
    //console.log(this.cities) 
}
```

**Service**

```
getCities() {
    return this.http.get(globalVar.serviceUrl + 'Cities').map((res: Response) => res.json());
}
```

Comment: how does your service look like?

Comment: Show your service. If results in service are fetched you should be able to see results using first console.log in your code.

Comment: try logging error in subscribe.. debug it

Comment: This is my service...


getCities() {
        
        return this.http.get(globalVar.serviceUrl + 'Cities')
            .map((res: Response) => 
               // console.log("Checking... " + res.json());
                res.json()
            );
    }

Comment: see the thing I am getting the result in cities bcoz i am able to see in my template..

Comment: Post your service code to the question.

Comment: but when I am logging it in the ngOnInit it is showing undefined

Comment: Both console.log() calls are commented out. The first one should log the citites. The second one will always log undefined. You get the response **asynchronously**. Unless of course the service fils: add a second callback to subscribe(). Use your debugger.

Comment: check if data fetched from service are ok by using console.log(data) instead of console.log(this.cities) in subscribe method

Comment: yeah first console.log is working now..

Comment: Thanks to all for the quick responses

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You could try to read response in other blocks of subscribe

```
this.cityAreaService.getCities().subscribe(
  response => {
    this.cities = response;
  },
  error => {
    // maybe error
  },
  () => {
    // anything else?
  }
);
```

Comment: There is no difference between the code from OP and yours.